# Подскажите стандартный "шаблон" Spring приложения (не MVC)

Tags: spring

Знакомлюсь со Spring и хотелось бы пойти чуть дальше Hello World и не пойму как строить приложение .
К примеру создал я бины, настроил их.
Создал точку входа вида:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
....
```

И дальше начинать дергать первый бин и т.д.

```
context.getBean(Bean1.class)
```

который потянет все остальные и "раскрутит" дальнейшую логику программы?

В интернете полно примеров, но все они не далеко уходят от HelloWorld (с 2-я,3 мя бинами) или все они MVC.

Мне кажется в реальных приложениях бины не достают в таком виде context.getBean(Bean1.class).
Подскажите "на пальцах" какой стандартный шаблон, или возможно где-то есть пример...

Спасибо.

Comment: https://github.com/Camelion/JTS-V3

Comment: Вам кажется. Достают.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev,  Не кажется, `@Autowired` используют

Comment: @NickSavenia ну так напишите ответ с примером того, как правильно инициализировать контекст и получить бин без `context.getBean()` в консольном приложении.